# Matplotlib line plot of Numpy array change color at specified percentage

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

Say you have a numpy array containing about 2000 elements of decimals ranging between 0 to 5.  Using matplotlib, how would you line plot the first 75% of these decimals in this numpy array in blue and the remaining 25% elements in red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code first creates some toy data with 2000 values between 0 and 5. The first 3/4<sup>th</sup> is plotted in blue, the rest in red.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(0, 5, 2000)
threefourth = len(data) * 3 // 4
plt.plot(range(threefourth+1), data[:threefourth + 1], color='dodgerblue')
plt.plot(range(threefourth, len(data)), data[threefourth:], color='crimson')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to apply this one to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might get away, depending on your data, by plotting first a blue line with all the data, and than plot a red line with the data of the lower decimals masked by replacing them with nan's with [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). See the following example. (Line segments that cross the red/blue border are problematic and will be plotted blue in this case.)

For a better control have a look at the [Multicolored lines](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-multicolored-line-py) example from the matplotlib documentation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xs = np.arange(0,2000)

ys = (   2.4 
       + 2.0 * np.sin(3 * 2 * np.pi * xs / 2000)
       + 0.3 * np.random.random(size=2000)
     )

red_ys = np.where( ys < 0.75 * 5 , np.nan , ys )

plt.plot(ys, 'b')
plt.plot(red_ys, 'r')

plt.show()
```

[image]